# возможно ли исправить день. недели?

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько дат, часть из которых по григорианскому календарю, а часть по юлианскому, дело в том что в датах по юлианскому календарю дни недели не совпадают с действительностью, возможно ли это исправить?

```js
function catholicDate(year) {
  // https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Гаусса_вычисления_даты_Пасхи
  // Пример на 1777 год (год рождения Карла Гаусса): год = 1777 
  // a = год mod 19 a = 10 
  var a = year % 19;
  // b = год mod 4 b = 1 
  var b = year % 4;
  // c = год mod 7 c = 6 
  var c = year % 7;
  // k = целая часть (год/100) k = 17 
  var k = Math.floor(year / 100);
  // p = целая часть ((13 + 8k)/25) p = 5 
  var p = Math.floor((13 + 8 * k) / 25);
  // q = целая часть (k/4) q = 4 
  var q = Math.floor(k / 4);
  // M = (15 - p + k - q) mod 30 M = 23 
  var m = (15 - p + k - q) % 30;
  // N = (4 + k - q) mod 7 N = 3 
  var n = (4 + k - q) % 7;
  // d = (19a + M) mod 30 d = 3 
  var d = (19 * a + m) % 30;
  // e = (2b + 4c + 6d + N) mod 7 e = 5 
  var e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + n) % 7;
  // Дата Пасхи по новому стилю: 22 + d + e марта или d + e - 9 апреля 30 марта 
  // Если d = 29 и e = 6, то вместо 26 апреля будет 19 апреля 
  if (d === 29 && e === 6)
    return new Date(year, 3, 19);
  // Если d = 28, e = 6 и (11M + 11) mod 30 < 19, то вместо 25 апреля будет 18 апреля 
  if (d === 28 && e === 6 && ((11 * m + 11) % 30 < 19))
    return new Date(year, 3, 18);
  if (d + e > 9)
    return new Date(year, 3, d + e - 9);
  else
    return new Date(year, 2, 22 + d + e);
}

function orthodoxDate(year) {
  // https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Гаусса_вычисления_даты_Пасхи
  // Разделить номер года на 19 и определить остаток от деления a.
  var a = year % 19;
  // Разделить номер года на 4 и определить остаток от деления b.
  var b = year % 4;
  // Разделить номер года на 7 и определить остаток от деления c.
  var c = year % 7;
  // Разделить сумму 19a + 15 на 30 и определить остаток d.
  var d = (19 * a + 15) % 30;
  // Разделить сумму 2b + 4c + 6d + 6 на 7 и определить остаток e.
  var e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 6) % 7;
  // Определить сумму f = d + e.
  var f = d + e;
  // (по старому стилю) Если f ≤ 9, то Пасха будет праздноваться 22 + f марта; если f > 9, то Пасха будет праздноваться f — 9 апреля.
  return f <= 9 ?
    new Date(year, 2, 22 + f) :
    new Date(year, 3, f - 9);
}
// Все даты отображаем в едином формате
function formatDate(date) {
  return date.toLocaleDateString("ru", {
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric"
  }).replace(/^.?|,/g, function(v, i) {
    return !i ? v.toUpperCase() : '<br>'
  });
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", document_domcontentloaded);


function document_domcontentloaded() {
  var Y = document.getElementById("YearEntry");

  Y.value = new Date().getFullYear();
  Y.addEventListener("input", function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, '')
  });

  document.getElementById("button1").onclick = button1_click;

  button1_click();
}

function button1_click() {
  var year = document.getElementById("YearEntry").value,
    razn = 0; //какое-то значение по умолчанию если меньше 300 и больше 4099

  if (year >= 300 && year <= 499) razn = 1;
  else if (year >= 500 && year <= 599) razn = 2;
  else if (year >= 600 && year <= 699) razn = 3;
  else if (year >= 700 && year <= 899) razn = 4;
  else if (year >= 900 && year <= 999) razn = 5;
  else if (year >= 1000 && year <= 1099) razn = 6;
  else if (year >= 1100 && year <= 1299) razn = 7;
  else if (year >= 1300 && year <= 1399) razn = 8;
  else if (year >= 1400 && year <= 1499) razn = 9;
  else if (year >= 1500 && year <= 1699) razn = 10;
  else if (year >= 1700 && year <= 1799) razn = 11;
  else if (year >= 1800 && year <= 1899) razn = 12;
  else if (year >= 1900 && year <= 2099) razn = 13;
  else if (year >= 2100 && year <= 2199) razn = 14;
  else if (year >= 2200 && year <= 2299) razn = 15;
  else if (year >= 2300 && year <= 2399) razn = 16;
  else if (year >= 2500 && year <= 2599) razn = 17;
  else if (year >= 2600 && year <= 2699) razn = 18;
  else if (year >= 2700 && year <= 2899) razn = 19;
  else if (year >= 2900 && year <= 2999) razn = 20;
  else if (year >= 3000 && year <= 3099) razn = 21;
  else if (year >= 3100 && year <= 3299) razn = 22;
  else if (year >= 3300 && year <= 3399) razn = 23;
  else if (year >= 3400 && year <= 3499) razn = 24;
  else if (year >= 3500 && year <= 3699) razn = 25;
  else if (year >= 3700 && year <= 3799) razn = 26;
  else if (year >= 3800 && year <= 3899) razn = 27;
  else if (year >= 3900 && year <= 4099) razn = 28;

  document.getElementById("Catholic_Easter_gr").innerHTML = formatDate(catholicDate(year));

  var date0_1 = catholicDate(year);
  document.getElementById("Catholic_Easter_gr").innerHTML = formatDate(date0_1);

  var date0 = new Date(date0_1.getFullYear(), date0_1.getMonth(), date0_1.getDate() - razn);
  document.getElementById("Catholic_Easter_ul").innerHTML = formatDate(date0);

  var date1 = orthodoxDate(year);
  document.getElementById("Orthodox_Easter_ul").innerHTML = formatDate(date1);

  var date1_1 = new Date(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate() + razn);
  document.getElementById("Orthodox_Easter_gr").innerHTML = formatDate(date1_1);

  var date2 = new Date(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate() + 9);
  document.getElementById("Orthodox_Radunitsa_ul").innerHTML = formatDate(date2);

  var date2_1 = new Date(date1_1.getFullYear(), date1_1.getMonth(), date1_1.getDate() + 9);
  document.getElementById("Orthodox_Radunitsa_gr").innerHTML = formatDate(date2_1);

  var date3 = new Date(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate() - 7);
  document.getElementById("palm_Sunday_Orthodox_ul").innerHTML = formatDate(date3);

  var date3_1 = new Date(date1_1.getFullYear(), date1_1.getMonth(), date1_1.getDate() - 7);
  document.getElementById("palm_Sunday_Orthodox_gr").innerHTML = formatDate(date3_1);

  var date4 = new Date(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate() - 49);
  document.getElementById("Maslenitsa_Orthodox_ul").innerHTML = formatDate(date4);

  var date4_1 = new Date(date1_1.getFullYear(), date1_1.getMonth(), date1_1.getDate() - 49);
  document.getElementById("Maslenitsa_Orthodox_gr").innerHTML = formatDate(date4_1);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 12px/9px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  margin: 0 20px 5px 0;
}

span.ulian {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 70%);
}

span.grig {
  color: hsl(240, 100%, 30%);
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="YearEntry" type="number" min="326" max="4099" step="1" value="2019" />
  <input id="button1" type="button" value="Расcчитать" />
</div>
<div>
  Первый Никейский собор — собор Церкви, созванный императором Константином I; состоялся в июне 325 года в городе Никее (ныне Изник, Турция); продолжался больше двух месяцев и стал первым Вселенским собором в истории христианства.<br> Введите год с 326
  по 4099</div>
<div>
  Католическая пасха<br>
  <span class="grig">
    <span id="Catholic_Easter_gr"></span><br> по григорианскому календарю (новый стиль)<br>
  </span>
  <span class="ulian">
    <span id="Catholic_Easter_ul"></span><br> по юлианскому календарю (старый стиль)
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  Православная пасха<br>
  <span class="grig">
    <span id="Orthodox_Easter_gr"></span><br> по григорианскому календарю (новый стиль)<br>
  </span>
  <span class="ulian">
    <span id="Orthodox_Easter_ul"></span><br> по юлианскому календарю (старый стиль)
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  Радуница<br>
  <span class="grig">
    <span id="Orthodox_Radunitsa_gr"></span><br> по григорианскому календарю (новый стиль)<br>
  </span>
  <span class="ulian">
    <span id="Orthodox_Radunitsa_ul"></span><br> по юлианскому календарю (старый стиль)
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  Вербное воскресенье<br>
  <span class="grig">
    <span id="palm_Sunday_Orthodox_gr"></span><br> по григорианскому календарю (новый стиль)<br>
  </span>
  <span class="ulian">
    <span id="palm_Sunday_Orthodox_ul"></span><br> по юлианскому календарю (старый стиль)
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  Масленица<br>
  <span class="grig">
    <span id="Maslenitsa_Orthodox_gr"></span><br> по григорианскому календарю (новый стиль)<br>
  </span>
  <span class="ulian">
    <span id="Maslenitsa_Orthodox_ul"></span><br> по юлианскому календарю (старый стиль)
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  Введите год с 326 по 4099</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно сначала исправить разметку ?

Comment: эх, если бы можно было исправлять дни....